# Commutator Subgroup of Thompson's Group $F$

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite non-abelian group. Is there any statement like this in group theory : If its commutator subgroup is simple then $G$ is simple?

Normally if $G$ is non-abelian, simple, its commutator subgroup is equal to $G$. But I wonder its inverse.

This is a question about Thompson's Group $F$. This group has the simple commutator subgroup. I want to prove that $F$ is simple.

Comment: $F$ is not simple. If it was then it would be perfect (i.e. equal to it commutator subgroup), but all of its relators are commutators, so $F/[F,F]$ is an infinite free abelian group of rank $2$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I misunderstood the notes that i read. My native language is not english and the paper i read is very difficult.

Comment: But what do you mean by saying relators? Did you mean $x_nx_k=x_kx_{n+1}$?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thompson group $F$ has the $2$-generator presentation $$\langle A , B\mid   [ A B^{-1} , A^{-1}B A ],\, [ A B^{-1}, A^{-2} B A^2 ]\rangle,$$
as described  in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups).

You can see immediately from this that $F/[F,F] \cong {\mathbb Z}^2$.