# Are commutator subgroups simple?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

I am interested in the following setting:

$$ 0\rightarrow [G,G]\rightarrow G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^r\rightarrow 0, $$
in particular in the case $r=1$. Is $[G,G]$ simple in this case?

I am aware of Thompson's group, but I do not know how to see if its commutator is simple in an easy way and also it is for the case $r=2$ instead of $r=1$ ([Commutator Subgroup of Thompson's Group $F$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044108/commutator-subgroup-of-thompsons-group-f)).

Comment: Given any perfect group $H$, the abelianization of $H \times \mathbb{Z}^r$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$, and the commutator subgroup is isomorphic to $H$. Not all perfect groups are simple, although all non-abelian simple groups are perfect.

Comment: Hi @GeoffreyTrang, if you convert your comment to an answer I will accept it as the solution. If you think it is too easy to be an answer maybe you can provide a non-simple perfect group of your choice (?). I am far from these kind of maths and I didn't think of this trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F$ be the (absolutely) free group of rank $r$. The lower central series of $F$ is defined recursively by
$$\begin{align*}
F_1 &= F;\\
F_{n+1} &= [F_n,F].
\end{align*}$$
The group $F/F_{n+1}$ is the relative free nilpotent group of class $n$ and rank $r$. The commutator subgroup is isomorphic to $[F,F]/F_{n+1}$, which is nilpotent and torsionfree, and in particular is not simple. But $F/[F,F]$ is free abelian of rank $r$, hence isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^r$.

Similarly, you can define the derived series of $F$,
$$\begin{align*}
F^{(0)} &= F,\\
F^{(n+1)} &= [F^{(n)},F^{(n)}].
\end{align*}$$
The quotient $F/F^{(n+1)}$ is the relatively free solvable group of length $n$ and rank $r$; it is solvable of length $n$, and the commutator subgroup is solvable of length $n-1$. The abelianization is free abelian of rank $r$.

There is absolutely no reason why the commutator subgroup of your $G$ would be free in such a situation.