# Commutator Subgroup of Thompson's Group F

Tags: group-theory, derived-subgroup

I am looking for a proof that the commutator subgroup of F is simple, I have found lots of articles about the commutator subgroup in general but havent found anything directly involving F and am struggling apllying the general case to F. Does anybody know of any articles that have this proof explicitily? Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Answer (score 2):

The book *Introduction to Thompson’s group $F$* by [Jose Burillo](https://web.mat.upc.edu/pep.burillo/F%20book.pdf) has an explicit and detailed proof, see Theorem $3.3.1$. See also the following post and the links given there:

[Commutator Subgroup of Thompson's Group $F$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3044108/commutator-subgroup-of-thompsons-group-f)

Comment: Very nice paper indeed! Thanks.